# Read JPG RGB values on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the values of the pixels of a jpg in unity, how can I do it? I'm seeing lots of methods but I do not know why they do not work for me. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag your jpg to projects, and assign it to the jpg property in your MonoScript

```
public Texture2D jpg;
var c = jpg.GetPixel(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the image to your project (i.e. you want to read from disk) you can use:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); //absolute or relative file path, e.g. Application.persistentDataPath
Texture2D jpg = new Texture2D(64,64); //size gets overwritten
jpg.LoadImage(bytes);
```

Then `Color c = jpg.GetPixel(x,y)` (as David answered) will get the pixel color value.